# right syntax using command sh in jenkinsfile

Tags: linux, jenkins, sh, jenkins-pipeline

I´m trying to remove image with same ids using a jenkinksfile, I´ve tried:

```
sh "docker images | grep 643975c526cf | awk '{print `$1` ':' `$2`}' | xargs docker rmi"

sh "docker images | grep 643975c526cf | awk '{print \$1 ':' \$2}' | xargs docker rmi"

sh "docker images | grep 643975c526cf | awk '{print ${1} ':' ${2}}' | xargs docker rmi"
```

but the syntax is wrong on awk '{print ${1} ':' ${2}}' in the linux using the command line work fine but I don´t know the right syntex on sh command.

Comment: Are you sure this works on the command line? That `awk` quoting looks suspicious.

Comment: Yes, I am. But I forgot one option more. the right option: sh "docker images | grep 643975c526cf | awk '{ print $1 ":" $2 }' | xargs docker rmi"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found this way and works fine:

```
sh """#!/bin/bash
    docker images | grep 643975c526cf  | awk '{print $1 ":" $2}' | sort -u | xargs docker rmi -f
   """
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below syntax.

```
sh "docker images | grep 643975c526cf | awk '{ print $1 ":" $2 }' | xargs docker rmi"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it does not work. Show:                              
            illegal string body character after dollar sign;
            solution: either escape a literal dollar sign "\$5" or bracket the 
            value expression "${5}"

Comment: Are you using Groovy script or shell ?

Comment: yes this is not working in jenkinsfile groovy sh syntax

Answer (score 0):

Next block of code used in Jenkins pipeline (it actual for shared libraries too)
In my case I get all process ID's, according to my application name from remote host. If you need get processlist from localhost - use **cmdFindPs** only

```
cmdSshConnect = "sshpass -p ${remPassword} ssh ${remLogin}@${remServer}"
cmdFindPs = 'ps aux | grep \'' + env.buildName +  '\' | awk \'{print $2}\''
cmdFillFindPs = cmdSshConnect + ' ' + cmdFindPs

//echo 'Command find = ' + cmdFillFindPs
runPs = sh(returnStdout: true, script: cmdFillFindPs)
//echo runPs.text
```